# external mSAS expansion

Tags: storage, intel, scsi, adaptec

I got two servers. One with a Intel RS2MB044 and one with an Adaptec ASR-51245, both got an external mSAS connector.

I need to connect these tho servers together, basically to share the file system like in a network share. I would like to use the SCSI cards to improve the performance.

Would that be possible or the mSAS port can be used only to connect other storage devices?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a critical piece, the device that both connect to to share.

You cannot connect two *controllers* together.  There needs to be something for them to actually control.

If you get past that part, you also need to find a filesystem that actually supports the ability to share simultaneously, such as GFS.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I do not have a lot of experience with SCSI devices, I usually only do simple tasks like create or delete arrays, that's it. My doubt was that there was a kind of functionality on SAS controller that allow to connect multiple controller together to share the array like in a network, would be great if you, for example, got an old server running out of space and do not have a way to increase the disk space otherwise, in that scenario would be also beneficial the fact that you are going to swap the server with a new one leaving the old one as a simple data storage.